# Why do I have to always clear the cache of the Download Manager in order to download 1 app?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, samsung, installation, download-manager

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy J4 Core with Android 8.1.0 Go. When ever I want to download an app on Google Play, I first have to clear my data/cache for my Download Manager and restart my phone. It then takes a very long time to even start the download... I'm not sure why I'm getting this bug.

Edit 1: If I don't clear my cache and restart my phone, no apps will download/update. It will just say "waiting for download...". Before I even thought of clearing my cache, I waited 3 days for my download to start...

Edit 2: I have 6GB free on my internal storage (max. 16GB) and 2GB on my 16GB SanDisk Card. I have 1GB RAM, though for some reason, 560MB is used all the time.

Comment: You should edit your question and also describe what bug you encounter if you don't clear the cache and restart. Otherwise it is very difficult to understand what you mean with "this bug".

Comment: @Robert I have edited my question :)

Comment: How many space is free on your device before clearing the cache?

Comment: @Robert, I have 6GB free on my internal storage (max. 16GB) and 2GB on my 16GB SanDisk Card.I have 1GB RAM, though for some reason, 560MB is used all the time.